# How do I watch the US presidential debates live via AppleTV?

Tags: appletv, airplay, youtube

I have a 3rd generation Apple TV. Will it be possible to use it to watch the US presidential debates live? I would prefer to do so without using AirPlay, if possible.

I know that today's (Oct 3, 2012) debate will be streamed live via [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/politics). Is the Apple TV's YouTube app capable of showing this? If so, how would I navigate to it?

If AirPlay is my only choice, how can I best go about it? I have:

- an iPhone 4S running iOS 5 (capable of both AirPlay for videos and AirPlay Mirroring)
- a Mac running OS X 10.7 (capable of AirPlay for videos, but not AirPlay mirroring)

Comment: [This list of streams](http://gigaom.com/video/presidential-debate-live-stream/) includes some iOS apps, so at worst I guess I'll try AirPlay from one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best bet right now seems to be AirPlay via the [CNN iPhone App](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cnn-app-for-iphone/id331786748?mt=8), which seems to provide higher quality than the other things I've tried.

[GigaOM has a long list of debate streams](http://www.youtube.com/politics). Here's what I've discovered about each one that might have promise:

## Success

- **CNN**: AirPlay via iPhone app. Appears to have the best video quality.
- **YouTube**: AirPlay via the [mobile site](http://m.youtube.com/politics) in iPhone's Safari appears to work! (Confirmed with pre-show live stream). Cannot find stream in any ove AppleTV app, Apple-provided iPhone app, nor YouTube-provided iPhone app.

## Might work

- **Ustream**: AirPlay via the [mobie site](http://m.ustream.tv/cbsnews) in iPhone's Safari *was* working, is currently unavailable. Unable to find stream in iPhone app

## Likely not possible

- **ABC News**: no indication the iPhone app will have a live stream; the article claims it will be available via [the iPad app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/abc-news-for-ipad/id380520716?mt=8).
- **C-SPAN**: website stream requires Flash, mobile site doesn't show stream
- **Hulu Plus**: AppleTV app gives no indication they will have the stream.
- **The Wall Street Journal**: AppleTV WSJ Live app says WSJ Live is unavailable.

## Not tried yet

- Politico
- Univision
- Aereo
- Ponderoo

Answer (score 2):

As the link you posted has several Pre-event streams scheduled, you can try things out before hand. I haven't seen a public announcement by either Google or Apple saying to tune in on your Apple TV, so you might plan on a second manner of streaming.

I'll likely use AirPlay mirroring to get the content onto my large screen via Apple TV.

[image]

Comment: The pre-show live stream *is* available on YouTube's mobile site, but not their Apple-provided nor YouTube-provided apps for iPhone, nor the YouTube Apple TV app.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the YouTube icon on the Apple TVs home screen. Just click it. If its available you'll find it.

Comment: I've edited my question to use the future tense to attempt to clarify that I'm trying to determine *in advance* whether they'll be available via the YouTube app when they start later tonight.

Comment: AFAIK YouTube on the ATV plays all content. I don't know if it *is* being streamed however.

Comment: Just checked your link - looks like your ATV can do it directly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Wall Street journal app on Apple TV live streaming the debates

Comment: Is it actually working for you? When I try to launch it, I get an error message that WSJ Live is unavailable.